# make tail wait for a file to exist

Tags: ubuntu, tail

`tail -f bar/somefile.log` would fail immediately when somefile.log does not exist. How do I make tail indefinitely wait for that file to be created (which will happen in a few moments)?

Update: using `-F`, I see:

```
tail: cannot open `bar/somefile.log' for reading: No such file or directory
tail: cannot watch parent directory of `bar/somefile.log': No such file or directory
```

because `bar` does't exist yet (it will be created in a few moments). when `bar` was created, and `somefile.log` was touched, tail didn't pick up the changes at all.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This works:

```
while ! tail -f bar/somefile.log ; do sleep 1 ; done
```

Comment: this is what finally worked for me (for missing parent directory cases).

Comment: Will this work for Mac?

Answer (score 43):

You're not mentioning which OS you need it for, but [`tail`on linux](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_tail.htm) has the --retry and --follow options that will do just that;

```
tail --retry --follow=name somefile.log
```

Comment: thanks, or `tail -F somefile.log`. but then, tail fails for a different reason (i've updated my question)

Answer (score 10):

Create the file first:

```
touch somefile ; tail -f somefile
```

Comment: Nice elegant logical solution.

Comment: Depending on the application, this might be the best solution.  Thanks!